# Automapper: Retrieve DTO mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

Assuming I have registered DTO's (which implement IBaseDto) to map to entities (which implement IUpdateEntity)

Now when I have a generic TEntity (currentItem), I want to find the correct DTO type it is mapped to.
I have the following code:

```
  var mappings = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps();
  var typeMap = mappings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.DestinationType == typeof (TEntity) &&   m.SourceType == typeof(BaseDto));
  if (typeMap != null)
  {
     var sourceType = typeMap.SourceType;

     var dto = currentItem.Map().To<sourceType>(); //map the entity to it's DTO
     var request = new SaveServiceRequest<sourceType> { Entity = currentItem }; // create a SaveServiceRequest
     SaveItem(request); //save the DTO
  }
```

Now the problem I'm having is on the line where I try to map the currentItem to a DTO.
VS/Resharper says It cannot resolve the symbol "sourceType".
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass generic type parameters as runtime arguments they need to be set at compile time.  Your code does not set the type parameter to the value in the `sourceType` variable, it is telling the compiler that the type is called sourceType so you are getting a compilation error as you have not defined a type called sourceType.

Comment: I see, so is there no way I can map to this unknown DTO? perhaps with reflection?

Comment: Your underlying issue is that you cannot set generic type parameters at runtime. You could map to a type to be decided at runtime using reflection but then you are still left with the problem that you cannot set the generic type parameter of `SaveServiceRequest`.